# Do Laravel 4 migration rollbacks execute in reverse order?

Tags: laravel, migration

I checked the docs but I can't confirm this: If you run php artisan migrate:rollback, do the various down() command run in reverse order?  For example, if I have the migration files:

```
2014-07-01_first_migration.php
2014-07-01_second_migration.php
2014-07-01_third_migration.php
```

Does rolling back fire ThirdMigration->down(), then SecondMigration->down(), and finally FirstMigration->down()?

Comment: It should - otherwise there are likely to be inconsistencies and errors. I haven't tried it, but I can't imagine it would be otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes, that is exactly how it works.

The longer answer is yes - this is because a migration might include things such as just adding a column to a table. If you didnt run them in reverse order, the table would be removed before the column is removed!

There are a few ways to reverse your migrations. This will only reverse the last migration operation:

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

And this will reverse **all** the migrations back to your initial DB:

```
php artisan migrate:reset
```

Comment: Ok - that's what I presumed, but I couldn't find anything specifically saying that.  Thanks!